# How do you create a Future in Dart with a lambda/higher-order function and resolve it?

Tags: dart

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to do the equivalent of the following Javascript code in Dart:

```
async function main(){
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 200);
    });

    // stuff after 200ms happens here
}
```

It's nice to be able to create a Promise and resolve it on the fly... can you also do this in dart? I've read about completers, but the examples use "regular" functions, rather than lambda/higher-order ones.

Comment: correction: change resolve() to resolve as pointed out by @lrn

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure what you want but you can write your own example as this in Dart:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main() async {
  print(DateTime.now().millisecond); // 417
  await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
  print(DateTime.now().millisecond); // 625
}
```

Maybe a more directly conversion would be:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main() async {
  print(DateTime.now().millisecond); // 417
  
  await () async {
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
  }();
  
  print(DateTime.now().millisecond); // 625
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The given ECMAScript snippet has an error, setTimeout is supposed to be called on a function, not `undefined`.
Also, it doesn't really need to be a lambda at all.

```js
function delay_200(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 200);
};
// statically allocated delay function

async function main() {
    await new Promise(delay_200);

    // stuff after 200ms happens here
}
```

Now, I haven't used Dart in quite some time, but I think it would be equivalent to the following:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
    await Future.delayed(
        Duration(milliseconds: 200)
    );

    // stuff after 200ms happens here
}
```

Now, I'm honestly not sure if you can construct a `Future` like you can a `Promise`, so I didn't really answer the primary question.

Comment: I've fixed the error, thanks. Also, the static method works fine in Dart as well, but I thought a lambda would be cleaner, especially if you only need to use the function once.

Comment: @concealedcurry Usually, yes, it is clearer, but it can be done in languages that don't support lambdas, I think older Dart didn't have lambdas. It was in response to what you had said about completers.